# Riemann Integral of discontinuous function

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, continuity

So I know you can integrate some discontinuous functions when the function is discontinuous at a finite number of points. So you can integrate for example this function on a interval [-1,3]:

$$ f(x):=\begin{cases} 
      x & x< \frac{1}{4} \\
      \frac{1}{x} & x\geq \frac{1}{4} 
   \end{cases}
$$

But can you integrate this function on a interval the discontinuous point as an end point? Like [-1,1/4]?

Comment: but this function $f$ is continuous?

Comment: my mistake, got the wrong function

Comment: It is right-continuous, hence integrable, if you redefine at 1/4